# Autohotkey: detecting the response of GUI

Tags: user-interface, testing, automation, autohotkey

I have a simple database application, for which I want to automate the following:

1. Click on 'View Table' button
2. Start timer
3. Wait till the content appears
4. End timer
5. Click on 'Close Table' button

repeat this process for 50 times and calculate the average time.

So, my question is:

I know how to do all other steps with autohotkey but 3. Is it possible to detect that the fetching operation is done, if I do not have code?

Comment: It's possible, but it depends on the program. When the content appears how is it displayed? If it's a new window you could use WinWaitActive. If it's just extra text added to a window then ControlGetText could be used to compare against the previous text to see if it's changed. Your question can't really be answered without some more information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gary Hughes said in the comment, one solution is to grab text of the window or text of a textbox and compare to see if its changed.

Another solution would be to take a screenshot of an area of the original or changed window that will always be there, and then do an `ImageSearch` to check if its visible or not.

Another would be to notice if a certain area of the window changes color when the content appears, and then do a `PixelSearch` to check for the visibility of a color at a certain x/y location.